# Entity Framework Code First - Many to Many without Collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, many-to-many

I began working with some many to many relationships in EF code first and found that I don't like having collections on my entities. I would much prefer the many to many relationships be handled in my repository so I can do something like `repository.GetUsersForOrganization(organization)`. My main concern is not exposing a collection on my entities and having a few methods on my repositories handle everything concerning the many to many relationships including fetching, adding, and deleting the relationships. I'm pretty much at a loss as to the best way to go about removing the collections and replacing it with the repository based approach. How have other people accomplished this?

Comment: Can I ask why you do not like having collections? Paired with lazy loading, User.Organizations and Organization.Users will work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to have navigation properties for many-to-many relations on your entities you will simply not map those many-to-many relations and you will instead map junction tables for many-to-many relations as separate entities and access them directly in your specialized methods in repository.

Comment: A correct yet obvious answer that I completely overlooked. Trying to be so abstracted away from the database made me forget for a moment out a database actually works. Thanks for the tip, I think I'm going to try out this method and see how it goes!